# How to test invalid input for encodeURIComponent()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How to write invalid input for `encodeURIComponent()`?

I browsed the documentation for [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent#exceptions). It mentions

> URIError: Thrown if uriComponent contains a lone surrogate.

How to test this while writing a unit test?

Comment: Did you read the article the "lone surrogate" links to?

Comment: @gre_gor Yes, I did. But I can't understand how to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an invalid unicode symbol. Something like this: `encodeURIComponent('\uDFFF');`

Comment: The problem was I used form control to send the payload, which leads somehow to reading it as a valid string, but when I try passing it directly to the function as you described, it worked!

Comment: Ah, it appeared to be an interesting case :)